# How to view class member variable in windbg？

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg

When I debug by windbg, I want to see the size of `m_pool`, there are two problems:

1. How to view the class member variable by `this` pointer.
2. How to view the size of stl::vector.

[image]

I try to use `dv` in command line, it seems doesn`t work:
[image]

Comment: Post screenshots instead of photos of screenshots. No, wait, you should post text instead of images.

Comment: do you have the stl.natvis file loaded?